# inference error when testing each element of a mixed-type list with "instanceof" in a ternary operator on a stream() in Java

Tags: java, types, stream, conditional-operator, instanceof

I know this could be a design flaw in Java, but I'd like to process a list with unknown types (easy to do in Python), mapping each element with a lambda function that tests the type and outputs something accordingly.

I tried to process a list of integers and a string, like so:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestMixedTypesArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> myArray = Arrays.asList(2, 3, "a", 5);
        myArray.stream().map(x -> x instanceof Integer ? x * x : x + x).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

I expected to be able to process each element according to it's types, but the compiler gives the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
        Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)
        The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object
        The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object
```

Comment: I managed to compile after type-casting the variables in the multiplication and sum operators:
 
`x -> x instanceof Integer ? (Integer) x * (Integer) x : (String) x + x`

But isn't there a better way?

Comment: myArray is a list of Objects and objects can not be mulitplayed there new feature in java but i am not sure which JDK version but it work fine with JDK 17 
        myArray.stream().map(x -> x instanceof Integer z ? z * z : String.valueOf(x).repeat(2)).forEach(System.out::println); check those tutorial https://dev.java/learn/pattern-matching/#instanceof

Comment: and python is dynamic typing language but java are static

Comment: *I expected to be able to process each element according to it's types* - You have a stream of `Object` type, and you're trying to add up two objects `x + x`, which doesn't make sense because `+` as well as other arithmetic operators a defined only for numeric primitives and their wrappers, and compiler is telling you that.

Comment: `x * x` also produces a compilation error because you need either to perform casting: `(Integer) x * (Integer) x` or use *Pattern matching for instanceof*: `x instanceof Integer intX ? intX * intX : x`